# Algorithm To Trim Both Sides of A Sequence

Tags: scala

I have a generator which produces sequences of numbers of varying length. For a specific value in a sequence, I want to produce a new sequence which has at most `10` elements to the right and left of this specific value. I tried the following but it's not working correctly:

```
xs.dropRight(xs.size - xs.indexOf(x) - 10).take(xs.size - xs.indexOf(x) + 10)
```

Some examples:

```
Vector(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22)
```

x = 11

```
Vector(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21)
```

x = 9

```
Vector(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)
```

x= 1

```
Vector(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
```

x = 18

```
Vector(8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the method [`slice`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.collection.GenTraversableLike@slice(unc_from:Int,unc_until:Int):Repr), which selects an interval of elements:

```
def myFun[T](value: T, xs: Seq[T], padding: Int) = {
  val idx = xs.indexOf(value)
  // padding + 1 because slice uses an exclusive upperbound
  xs.slice(idx - padding, idx + padding + 1)
}

scala>   myFun(3, 0 to 50, 10)
res2: Seq[Int] = Vector(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)

scala>   myFun(10, 0 to 50, 10)
res3: Seq[Int] = Vector(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
```

Comment: I don't think the `max` and `min` are necessary here but otherwise it looks like it works for all cases.

Comment: Yep I peaked at the sources for slice and you are correct I.K.  I'll edit them out.

Answer (score 1):

You're just doing the math wrong.  Let's draw a picture of various cases

```
.......0987654321x123                 <-- ending short
              321x1234567890.......   <-- beginning short
.......0987654321x1234567890.......   <-- lots of room
                 ^--- you want this one
                      val index = xs.indexOf(x)
```

Now, we want to drop everything beyond ten elements before.  Drop ignores negative elements, so it doesn't matter if the beginning is short, we can just `drop(index - 10)`.  Now our picture is

```
     0987654321x123                 <-- beginning clipped, end short
            321x1234567890.......   <-- beginning short
     0987654321x1234567890.......   <-- beginning clipped, end long
```

Now our position of `x` may have changed (if we dropped anything).  If not, we just take 10 after `index`.  If so, we take 21--all 10 we kept, plus `x`, plus ten after.  (If there aren't that many left, `take` doesn't care.)

```
xs.drop(index - 10).take(if (index > 10) 21 else index + 10)
```

And we've now cut off the end.

You can simplify the math a little by using `slice`, which takes start and end indices.  But there's no inherent reason why drop/take doesn't work; you just need to count carefully.  In particular, your solution would have worked if instead of `xs` in the `take` you had found `indexOf(x)` in the new thing you'd created.  (Kind of wasteful to look for it again instead of using math, but it works.)